# Correct use of heatsink tape

Tags: hardware

With my Rpi 3B+, I got a heatsink kit, RS Stock No. 867-9039. Two large heatsinks and one small, and a short length of kind of tape stuff, with the 3M logo and what looks like the word "Adhesive" printed on it. As far as I can see, the SOC takes a large one, and the Ethernet chip a small one. Not sure what the other large one is for.

What I can't work out is how to use the tape. It seems to be layered, and maybe I have to peel it somehow (seems tricky to do that)? But what then? I guess I must cut it up to make little patches. Must I wet it or what?

[image]

Comment: thermal tape is double sticky.  First cut to the size of heat sink, peel one side off, stick to heat sink (Note1 ), peel other side off, then carefully align to one side, stick one edge first, see all align well, then press from edge to whole surface. Note 1 - Or you can first cut to a roughly bigger size, peel one side off, stick to heat sink, then cut to more exact size, ... Also watch this youtube: ( https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+heat+sink+tape&oq=how+to+use+heat+sink+tape&aqs=chrome..69i57.9351j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=1 )

Comment: @tlfong01 Why not make that an answer?

Comment: It's not like in that video. Doesn't seem to be "double sided"; it's brown, and appears to have only 2 layers. One side is shiny and the other is matte and has "3M Adhesive" printed on it. The two layers can be peeled apart exposing a sticky surface (one only). You can stick this to the underside of the heat sink but there is no other layer to peel off, or if there is it is impossible for me to get it apart.

Comment: The heatsink kit is specific to the Raspberry Pi, at least as described by RS Components, a main supplier.

Answer (score 2):

Update: after trying to peel a layer off the square of tape which was on the heatsink, I got cross and just ripped the square off. I saw that it had left a layer of adhesive sticky stuff on the heatsink. I pressed the heatsink on the SOC and after a few minutes it was stuck so hard I could pick up the whole Pi, case and all, by grasping the heatsink. I have done some tests and before, if I loaded the Pi by running sysbench continuously, the temp went up to 82 C, now it stays around 70. So I think I may have found the correct use of the tape.